# Named parameters in exec component

Tags: apache-camel

In Apache Camel we can used named parameters in the sql component, like so:

```
sql:select * from table where id=:#myId order by name[?options]
```

Is there a way to do the same with the exec component - a.ka.:

```
exec:myfile.bat?args=id=:#myId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No but you can use dynamic to, which would give you similar thing. Where you can use the simple language etc to build the url dynamic.

- http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Comment: Thanks for the idea Claus - I define the exec parameters in a property file so I instead created a bean which does  the named parameters resolution in a header field